# umbraco content tree nodes to json format

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have an umbraco website with the following content structure:
(the text in brackets is the nodeTypeAlias)

```
[root]
 - [child]
 |  - [module]
 |  |  - [submodule]
 |  |  - [submodule]
 - [child]
 |  - [module]
 |  - [module]
 |  |  - [submodule]
```

I am trying to export the above structure (together with the node's properties) into the following json file:

```
{
    "root": {
        "child": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Child 1",
                "module": [
                    {
                        "id": "2",
                        "name": "Module 1",
                        "submodule": [
                            {
                                "id": "3",
                                "name": "Sub module 1"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "4",
                                "name": "Sub module 3"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "5",
                "name": "Child 5",
                "module": [
                    {
                        "id": "8",
                        "name": "Module 8"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "6",
                        "name": "Module 6",
                        "submodule": [
                            {
                                "id": "7",
                                "name": "Sub module 7"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "9",
                                "name": "Sub module 9"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So far I've wrote down the following code in Linqpad but the result is not the one that I was looking for.

```
List<Node> brands = new List<Node>()
{               
    new Node
    {
         id = 1,
        name = "Brand 1",
        type = "brand",
        children = new List<Node>
        {        
            new Node
            {
                id = 2,
                name = "Shelf 1",
                type = "shelf",
                children = new List<Node>
                {
                    new Node
                    {
                        id = 1,
                        name = "Bookcase 1",
                        type = "bookcase"
                    },
                    new Node
                    {
                        id = 2,
                        name = "Bookcase 2",
                        type = "bookcase"
                    },
                    new Node
                    {
                        id = 3,
                        name = "Bookcase 3",
                        type = "bookcase"
                    }
                }
            },
            new Node
            {
                id = 3,
                name = "Shelf 2",
                type = "shelf",
                children = new List<Node>
                {
                    new Node
                    {
                        id=1,
                        type= "module",
                        name = "Module 1"
                    },
                    new Node
                    {
                        id=2,
                        type= "pdf",
                        name = "PDF 1"
                    },
                    new Node
                    {
                        id=3,
                        type= "link",
                        name = "Link 1"
                    },
                    new Node
                    {
                        id=4,
                        type= "link",
                        name = "Link 2"
                    },
                }
            }                   
        }
    },

    new Node
    {
        id = 2,
        name = "Brand 2",
        type = "brand",
        children = new List<Node>
        {
            new Node
            {
                id = 2,
                name = "Shelf 1",
                type = "shelf",
            },
            new Node
            {
                id = 3,
                name = "Shelf 2",
                type = "shelf",
            }
        }
    }
};


Result container = new Result();

Action<List<Node>, Result> add = null;
add = (nodes, coll) =>
{
    List<Result> list = null;
    if(nodes != null && nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        nodes.Dump("nodes");
        foreach(var node in nodes)
        {
            string key = node.type;
            list = null;
            if(coll.Children.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                list = coll.Children[key];
            }
            else
            {
                list = new List<Result>();
            }
            Result r = new Result();
            r.Name = node.name;
            add(node.children, r);
            list.Add(r);
            coll.Children[key] = list;
            coll.Dump("coll");
        }
    }
};

add(brands, container);
container.Dump();
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(container).Dump();
}

public class Result
{
    public Result()
    {
        this.Children = new Dictionary<string, List<Result>>();
        this.Properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> Properties {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, List<Result>> Children {get;set;}
}

public class Node
{
    public string name{get;set;}
    public string type {get;set;}
    public int id {get;set;}
    public List<Node> children{get;set;}
```

result:

```
{
    "Name": null,
    "Properties": {},
    "Children": {
        "brand": [
            {
                "Name": "Brand 1",
                "Properties": {},
                "Children": {
                    "shelf": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Shelf 1",
                            "Properties": {},
                            "Children": {
                                "bookcase": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "Bookcase 1",
                                        "Properties": {},
                                        "Children": {}
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Name": "Bookcase 2",
                                        "Properties": {},
                                        "Children": {}
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Name": "Bookcase 3",
                                        "Properties": {},
                                        "Children": {}
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Shelf 2",
                            "Properties": {},
                            "Children": {
                                "module": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "Module 1",
                                        "Properties": {},
                                        "Children": {}
                                    }
                                ],
                                "pdf": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "PDF 1",
                                        "Properties": {},
                                        "Children": {}
                                    }
                                ],
                                "link": [
                                    {
                                        "Name": "Link 1",
                                        "Properties": {},
                                        "Children": {}
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Name": "Link 2",
                                        "Properties": {},
                                        "Children": {}
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "Brand 2",
                "Properties": {},
                "Children": {
                    "shelf": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Shelf 1",
                            "Properties": {},
                            "Children": {}
                        },
                        {
                            "Name": "Shelf 2",
                            "Properties": {},
                            "Children": {}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much the way that you would go about generating XML, but JSON is a little different. If you have updated your Umbraco to one of the later editions, then you use Razor to render JSON in this sort of way:

```
    @{
    var builder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();              
    foreach (var car in cars)
    {            
    builder.Append("{");
    builder.Append(Json.Encode("reg") + ":" + Json.Encode(car.Registration) + ",");
    builder.Append(Json.Encode("model") + ":" + car.Model);

    // INSERT OTHER VALUES HERE     

    builder.Append("}");
    if (car.Registration != cars.Last().Registration)
    {
    builder.Append(",");
    }
    count++;
    }
    }
    @Html.Raw(builder.ToString())
```

Another more interesting way is JSON.NET - a good option if you are using custom objects in your application.  You populate your objects, and then pass them through JSON.NET. [See here for more details](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

The beauty of this library is that you can also create strings and convert them to JSON.  The only caveat is that you have to watch your JavaScript when trying to read the JSON. Things like single (') and double (") quotes can break your code.

```
string json = @"{
  ""Name"": ""Apple"",
  ""Expiry"": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
  ""Price"": 3.99,
  ""Sizes"": [
    ""Small"",
    ""Medium"",
    ""Large""
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

string name = (string)o["Name"];
// Apple

JArray sizes = (JArray)o["Sizes"];

string smallest = (string)sizes[0];
// Small
```

Your code could work if you used the System.Xml namespace (XmlDocument, XmlAttributes, XmlNode). It is unclear as to which Node object you are using but I will assume it is Umbraco's Node (I would work with a new DynamicNode() instead btw) and in which case you cannot just create them like that with populated properties. You have to create one in the Umbraco database before reading its values.

Hopefully this should give you something to go on with. *Happy coding*.